# Makefile Flags selections

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-flags

Just a general question regarding Makefile, which flags are recommended that I always have when compiling my C++ code to guarantee that the compilation is made as safe as possible ?

For now I am using these flags :

```
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++17
```

Comment: That's a good start. Why do you think you need more, or different, flags and options? And what do you mean with "as safe as possible"?

Comment: also -pedantic can help

Comment: `-Wconversion -Wold-style-cast -Wpedantic` are helpful as well

Comment: FWIW this isn't really related to makefiles at all.  It's a compiler question.  Also note that the flags available to you depend on which compiler you're using.

Comment: @MadScientist So depending if I am using g++,gcc or gdb I should pick different flags for the compiler ? How do I know which ones should I pick ? for example I am using the g++ compiler right know

Comment: Well, first `gdb` is not a compiler it's a debugger.  Second, `g++` and `gcc` are both in the same tool: GCC is GNU Compiler Collection and contains `gcc` (a C compiler), `g++` (a C++ compiler), as well as other languages.  You look at the documentation for your compiler and see what options it provides, and what those options do.  Searching Google for "GCC manual" for example will get you to where you want to be.

Comment: Some flags are appropriate only for some languages (C/C++)  But other compilers such as Clang, Microsoft Visual Studio, etc. have different flags even for the same language.